# Different phase response plots using MATLAB's $\tt freqz$ and $\tt fvtool$?

Tags: matlab, filters, butterworth

I have a butterworth filter in MATLAB:

```
[B, A] = butter( 2, 3000/16000*2, 'high' );
```

I plot it in two ways:

- using `freqz`:

  ```
  [h,w] = freqz(B,A,8000);
  plot(w);
  ```
- and using `fvtool`:

  ```
  h = fvtool(B,A);
  h.Analysis = 'phase';
  h.Fs = 16000;
  h.FrequencyRange='[-Fs/2, Fs/2)';
  ```

First plot gives me linear phase, and second one not.

Why do I get different plots?

Comment: `plot(w)` only plots the frequencies while `h` is the response. Same mistake as in your previous question.

Comment: yes, goti it, thanks. `w` are only x-axis frequencies, phase needs to be calculated from the complex amplitudes. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the help output of freqz:

```
[H,W] = freqz(B,A,N) returns the N-point complex frequency response
vector H and the N-point frequency vector W in radians/sample of
the filter.
```

So, your output is not amplitude and phase, but (complex) transfer function and frequency. Hence, to plot the phase using freqz you need to use

```
plt(w, angle(h));
```